# Why is the difference of two sigmoid/tanh functions like a bowl but the addition is monotonic?

Tags: calculus, curves

I am trying to plot two functions -

 

`1. Z = sigmoid(sigmoid(x+y-1.5) - sigmoid(x+y-0.5) - 1.5)`

`2. Z = tanh(tanh(x+y-1.5) - tanh(x+y-0.5) - 1.5)`

The images for sigmoid function is as follows:-

`1a. Z = sigmoid(x+y-1.5)`

[image: sigmoid(x+y-1.5)]

`1b. Z = sigmoid(x+y-0.5)`

[image: sigmoid(x+y-0.5)]

`1c. Z = sigmoid(sigmoid(x+y-1.5) + sigmoid(x+y-0.5) - 1.5)`

[image: sigmoid(sigmoid(x+y-1.5) + sigmoid(x+y-0.5) - 1.5)]

`1d. Z = sigmoid(sigmoid(x+y-1.5) - sigmoid(x+y-0.5) - 1.5)`

[image: Z = sigmoid(sigmoid(x+y-1.5) - sigmoid(x+y-0.5) - 1.5)]

Same story is holding even for tanh.

What is confusing me is that while the constituent functions and there sum are monotonically increasing functions, the functions in the questions are bowl shaped. It has been my understanding that sum/difference of two monotonically decreasing functions is also monotonic but this is not the case here. Can you please help me understand this?

Comment: Sum yes, but difference clearly no (in general).

Comment: I am getting that now. Any intuition as to why this is the case? Any example that I make up leads me to believing that even difference should be monotonic

Comment: No formulas needed, just draw two decreasing curves. There's no reason for why the *distance* between these two curves would have to be decreasing, is there? The curves could equally well get further apart (if the lower curves is decreasing faster).

Comment: But if you want formulas, consider for example the decreasing functions $f(x) = -2x+\sin x$ and $g(x)=-2x$.

Comment: When you are talking about distance between the curves, do you mean distance between corresponding points of the curves?

Comment: Yes, the vertical distance $f(x)-g(x)$ between the curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$.

Comment: You’re basically looking at the graph of arctan x - arctan (x+1). Google that and you will see the shape of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Sum is ok but not the difference always for monotonicity as also commented by MPW.

Differentiating their difference, derivative may or may not be monotonous but can have one or two or more extrema. It all depends on the difference of individual *rates*.

For the difference of two increasing functions

$$ \tan^{-1}x -\tan^{-1}(x+1)$$

[two extrema are seen](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot-%20%282%20x%2B1%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B%202%20x%20%2B2%29%2C%20%28x%2C-4%2C4%29) in this plot.